# SAILS-CBES adapter key, what is it?

Tags: sails.js, couchbase

I had issues correctly configuring my couchbase adapter in sails-js.  I am using the sails-cbes adapter.  The documentation fails to mention the key to use.  For any who might struggle as I did, below is my configuration file:

```
{
...
//couchbase
cb: {
    adapter: 'sails-cbes',
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 8091,
    user: 'user',
    pass: 'password',

    bucket: {
        name: 'bucket',
        pass: 'bucketPassword'
    }
}

},
...
```

Comment: So I believe that sails-cbes is the correct adapter key, however, there is something not quite right with my installation of the adapter.  When I try to run the test script, they fail.  missing dependencies...

Comment: I did confirm that sails-cbes is the correct adapter key.  I now have an access issue to the couchbase bucket.  I will update my post.

Comment: Original post has been updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that by 'key' you refer to the 'password' fields:

The first password is the one you set up in the dialogue the first time you log in to `https://localhost:8091`.

The bucket is not being created automatically so you would have to do that manually in couchbase. Then you have the option to set a password for the bucket itself, but the default is just empty string. Elasticsearch indexing is automated as long as you declare the mapping in the model.

The configuration file should be in `sails-project/config/connections.js` and it should look something like this:

```
sailsCbes: {
    adapter: 'sails-cbes',
    cb: { ... },
    es: { ... }
}
```

You can try it out by creating a model within sails that uses this connection.

As for the dependencies, you need to install couchbase and elasticsearch yourself, then from the sails-cbes folder do a `sudo npm install` and you should be good to go. For test dependencies, run npm install inside the test folder.

Hope this helps

Comment: thank you for the explanation.  I have successfully updated my connection configuration.

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't understand how sailsjs adapter works.
Please spend some time and read the documentation of sailsjs, specially the connections configuration (adapters)

http://sailsjs.org/#!/documentation/reference/sails.config/sails.config.connections.html